# roscpp cannot understand a single cpp keyword

Tags: ros, compile, ros-kinetic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've written a package and I can succesfully use it's node and i have sended the package to my friend.
He wanted to compile my package in his pc by catkin make but faced this error:

```
metobom@metobom-TULPAR-T5-V17-1:~$ rosrun mpk2 mrc.cpp
/home/metobom/metos_ws/src/mpk2/src/mrc.cpp: line 4: //#include: No such file or directory
/home/metobom/metos_ws/src/mpk2/src/mrc.cpp: line 9: using: command not found
/home/metobom/metos_ws/src/mpk2/src/mrc.cpp: line 10: double: command not found
/home/metobom/metos_ws/src/mpk2/src/mrc.cpp: line 11: float: command not found
/home/metobom/metos_ws/src/mpk2/src/mrc.cpp: line 13: struct: command not found
/home/metobom/metos_ws/src/mpk2/src/mrc.cpp: line 14: double: command not found
/home/metobom/metos_ws/src/mpk2/src/mrc.cpp: line 15: double: command not found
/home/metobom/metos_ws/src/mpk2/src/mrc.cpp: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
/home/metobom/metos_ws/src/mpk2/src/mrc.cpp: line 16: `};'
```

So what is the actual problem, can he solve it without reinstalling everything.

Thanks for answers im looking forward to solve it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315456/roscpp-cannot-understand-a-single-cpp-keyword/) by [umut](https://answers.ros.org/users/39446/umut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your friend needs to compile your C++ code (by running `catkin_make`) before he can run it, and then needs to run the compile executable instead of trying to run the .cpp file.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [umut](https://answers.ros.org/users/39446/umut/) on 2019-02-16**:
Thank you so much that you gave an answer for such question, I've realized how dummy me and my friend are.